# Is there a way to force terminate a worker thread in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I was looking around for my question but to no avail. I wanted to know if there was a way to force a worker to terminate a worker thread even if its task hadn't been completed. I have some code in there that calls itself if it somehow fails, which is intentional even though it might be bad code practice. I tried using libraries such as microjob and threads, but those didn't have what I wanted. Here is what I tried to do with threads but didn't work:

```
// Module part of threads (taskModule)
expose(async function startTask(taskData, profileData, taskID) {

    await _Task.FetchData(taskData);
    await _Task.GenerateSession(profileData);
    await _Task.RequestPermission(taskID);
    await _Task.SubmitOrder();

    return "finished";
})
```

```
// Runs the module (main.js)
const {spawn, Thread, Worker} = require("threads");

let task = null;

async function test() {
    task = await spawn(new Worker('./taskModule'))
    startTask({},{},"0")
}

setTimeout(async function() {
    await Thread.terminate(task)
}, 3000)

test().then(() => {
    console.log('hello')
}).catch(console.error)
```

I was trying to test to see if the code would stop after 3 seconds to test, but it seems like it just continues. Is there a better way to do this type of task?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Oh, and to clarify, the _Task stuff is defined just above the expose function.

Comment: Are you aware of [`worker.terminate()`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_terminate) and does that not do what you want?  If not, then you may have to use a child_process where you can kill that whole child_process.

Comment: Using `setTimeout()` to call `worker.terminate()` on yourself will NOT get called until your worker thread gets back to the event loop to process the timer event from the `setTimeout()`.  So, that structure will never terminate a worker that is busy doing a bunch of synchronous code that isn't returning control back to the event loop.  You could perhaps do a timeout from the main thread and kill the worker from there.

Comment: It sounds like you really ought to just fix your code so it is either reliable or so it catches and handles its own errors.  You shouldn't just be running code that sometimes needs to be killed.  IMO, that's just bad code that should be eliminated/fixed.  I'd put effort into that rather than slapping some sort of bandaid on it.

Comment: I'll look into the child_process, oh and I need it to be terminated sometimes because the user controls it and it needs to be killed whenever they click the stop button.

Comment: Well, if the code in the worker thread is processing events, you can just send it a message to tell it to stop itself and it will process that event when it next gets back to the event loop.  Nodejs is an event driven system - that's how you should be designing your code.  Perhaps you need to restructure the worker thread code so that it processes events.  We can't really help with the bigger picture here without knowing more about the code in the worker thread, what it's doing and how it's written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by using clusters in Node.JS, which uses the `child_process` to run the workers.

Here is a link to the documentation if anyone needs it: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand the difference between the cluster package and the `worker_thread` package.

the former is running multiple instances of node.js application as processes, that distributes workloads among their application threads, in this case, you do not have full control of this threads as it's system managed, while the former creates a thread you can fully manage, they can both solve this particular problem, but there are sometimes the use cases might be more peculiar and different.

To solve the problem with a managed thread use the `worker_thread` package especially if you want communication or return of response or data to the main thread.

```
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
```

Setup the Worker class and assign a task to it, which is implemented a separate JS file, like so.

```
const worker = new Worker("path to the worker thread", {
  workerData: {data: "data to the worker thread"},
});
```

Add the path to the worker thread and any data you might want to pass through.

You can receive the data or pass message to the main thread using properties on  `workerData` and the `parentPort`.

```
const { workerData, parentPort } = require("worker_threads");
```

You can terminate the worker by call the terminate method on the worker class, if you don not wish the task to continue, like in your own case, like so.

```
worker.terminate();
```

You can wrap the worker class in a new promise, it all depends on how you want to manage it.

Comment: out of curiosity, did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?